# How to connect R-studio to Oracle Database and also add external file csv to the queried data for ShinyDashBoard in R?

Tags: r, oracle, oracle11g, rstudio, shinydashboard

Below is the scenario.

**Scenario:**
I am building `ShinyDashBoard` that will allow end users to track system usability at specific location.

For this I need two tables that are in Oracle Database (As explained below). Also,I have one `csv` file that I would like to join after data is queried. This `csv` file contains data regarding System location. The purpose of joining `csv` file is to retrieve data of all systems located at specific location. This csv file consist of *System, Location columns*. From end-user perspective they would like to see where all systems are located, and at what frequency are those system being used ?

**Table1** consists of User login information. It consist of *UserName, UserLogin Date* columns

**Table2** consist of data regarding which user is using which system.(This table does not contain data of all systems, it only contains data where the system is being currently used). This table consist of *UserName and System* column.

**Question #1**: My question is how to approach in building the App ? I read this [post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/connecting-r-to-an-oracle-database/) where author suggest it's possible to connect to Oracle Database in `R-Studio` using RODBC package. However, I am not sure where should I put the code for connecting to Oracle database ? Does connection code goes in Global environment ? or does it go in `Sever` part of shiny App ?

**Question #2**: How to join external data ?  I know I can perform Join on my Table1 and Table2 on "UserName" column. Then I can perform Join on "System" column that is in csv file.Where should the code for Join go ?

**Question #3**: Regarding username and password part of RODBC package.Since, end-users will be different persons using the app. What should I put for username and password  when deploying the application?

I know this question covers various areas, if possible provide basic syntax of how would basic `ShinyDashBoard` app look like, which can connect to Oracle Database, and query the data  from two table and perform join with external csv file,and render data on `ShinyDashboard` in form of visualization.

Comment: You can use `DBI` with `odbc` to connect to the database; an alternative it the `RODBC` package. While I prefer the former, I'm confident others prefer the latter. There are many tutorials on how to connect in R, starting with https://db.rstudio.com/ (and still many many others). "Joining data" is the same whether externally-queried or not: once in R, it does not matter; one such question is https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials that combine shiny and db connections too.

Comment: @r2evans.. Thanks! Would it be possible to share link of few tutorials ? I couldn't find any on YouTube. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I gave two in the first comment, I'd start there. Otherwise, google, rstudio, and r-bloggers typically have good blogs/tutorials/entries.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Oracle you will need RJDBC package. 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html